# Using 'sync' when wiping a device with /dev/urandom

Tags: linux, dd, usb-drive, usb-device

Is it necessary to synchronize cached writes to persistent storage with the `sync` command when wiping a USB, or any device, with `/dev/urandom`?

This is a common practice, i.e. `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx && sync`.

But is that really necessary? Is it okay to omit the `sync` command?

*Please note* this question is not referring to the `conv=sync` option of the `dd` utility, it refers to `sync` as a stand alone command that can also be used apart from `dd`. Here is a reference to [sync](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html), and 
here is a reference to [conv=sync](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html). Both are from https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.

Thank you

Comment: You can omit sync of course. Keep in mind if there is caching involved, that not all the writes are not necessarily on the medium. sync ensures that before countinuing.

Comment: Are you sure that you need `/dev/urandom`? I think it is good enough to wipe a USB drive or memory card with zeros from `/dev/zero` which is faster. And there are other tools to wipe a HDD or SSD, tools that are more efficient than `dd`. Ask for details, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sync` isn’t used specifically because `/dev/urandom` is involved; it’s used to ensure that all pending writes have been sent to the device. This is especially important when using removable devices: running `sync`, and waiting for it to finish, ensures that the device can be safely removed.

When wiping a device, if you omit the `sync` and disconnect the device, you might not have finished wiping the device...

Answer (score 0):

The `sync()` call is related to filesystems - not to devices.

If you write to a block device, `sync()` may cause a buffer flush, but if you use the raw device, as recommended in this case, `sync()` does not make sense.

WARNING: On Linux, it may be hard to find out the related raw device. Check the Linux documentation on how to get the related raw device.